# while(i--) optimization by gcc and clang: why don't they use sub / jnc?

Tags: c, performance, gcc, assembly, x86

Some people write such code when they need a loop without a counter or with a `n-1, ..., 0` counter:

```
while (i--) { ... }
```

A specific example:

```
volatile int sink;
void countdown_i_used() {
    unsigned i = 1000;
    while (i--) {
         sink = i;  // if i is unused, gcc optimizes it away and uses dec/jnz
    }
}
```

On GCC 8.2 ([on the Godbolt compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(fontScale:1.2899450879999999,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,source:'%23include+%3Cstdint.h%3E%0A%0Avolatile+int+sink%3B%0Avoid+countdown_i_used()+%7B%0A++++unsigned+i+%3D+1000%3B%0A++++while+(i--)+%7B%0A+++++++++sink+%3D+i%3B%0A++++%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Avoid+countdown_i_unused()+%7B%0A++++unsigned+i+%3D+1000%3B%0A++++while+(i--)+%7B%0A+++++++++sink+%3D+123%3B%0A++++%7D%0A%7D'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:35.17897589003274,l:'4',m:100,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g82,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',libraryCode:'1',trim:'1'),fontScale:1.2899450879999999,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-O3+-Wall+-Wextra+-march%3Dhaswell',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+8.2+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%232)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),header:(),k:31.741689042939807,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang700,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',libraryCode:'1',trim:'1'),fontScale:1.2899450879999999,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-O3+-Wall+-Wextra',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+clang+7.0.0+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),header:(),k:33.07933506702746,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4)), it's compiled into

```
# gcc8.2 -O3 -march=haswell
.L2:
    mov     DWORD PTR sink[rip], eax
    dec     eax                      # with tune=generic,  sub eax, 1
    cmp     eax, -1
    jne     .L2
```

---

On clang (https://godbolt.org/z/YxYZ95), if the counter is not used it turns into

```
if(i) do {...} while(--i);
```

but if used, like GCC it turns into

```
add esi, -1
cmp esi, -1
jnz lp
```

---

**However, this seems to be a better idea:**

```
sub esi, 1
jnc lp
```

**Why don't these two compilers use this way?**

Because the `cmp` way is better?  Or because they won't save space this way and they are almost the same speed?

Or do they just not consider this option?

---

Update: Even if I write code to use the carry way (Here I use `add/jc` but it's same)

```
bool addcy(unsigned& a, unsigned b) {
    unsigned last_a = a;
    a+=b;
    return last_a+b<last_a;
}
volatile unsigned sink;
void f() {

    for (unsigned i=100; addcy(i, -1); ) {
        sink = i;
    }
}
```

[compiler still compile it as checking equality to -1](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/y7ZyvK). However, if the 100 is replaced with an input, [the JC code remain](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/QaUrYe)

Comment: Post [mcve]. Also make sure you enabled optimization.

Comment: gcc is surprisingly bad at optimizing loops down to one macro-fused uop of overhead.  With `for(int i=0 ; i < size ; i++)` loops, you tend to get `add` / `cmp/jcc` instead of `dec size/jnz` even if `i` is unused inside the loop.  But yes `sub` / `jnc` would probably be optimal; that can macro-fuse on Sandybridge-family.

Comment: It looks like you're using `i` inside the loop, otherwise gcc does better.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, this is a missed optimization.  Intel Sandybridge-family can macro-fuse sub/jcc into a single uop, so sub/jnc saves code-size, x86 instructions, and uops on those CPUs.

On other CPUs (e.g. AMD which can only fuse test/cmp with jcc), this still saves code size so it's at least slightly better.  It's not worse on anything.

It would be a good idea to report missed-optimization bugs on https://bugs.llvm.org and https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/.

Comment: Found that gcc even compile a `jc` code back into `jnz` code, so what's happening?

Comment: @l4m2: You don't have a literal `jc` in your update, you just have an idiom that compilers *can* recognize as a carry-out check.  But with a constant trip-count, the compiler can see when the loop will end and compile it in the sub-optimal way it apparently prefers.  Report a missed-optimization bug if you want compiler devs to change gcc and LLVM to not screw this up.